# Symfony2 cache and routing generation

Tags: model-view-controller, caching, symfony, routes

this is my first attempt to create something with Symfony2.
I have my database, and I wanted to generate models from it automatically. So I run

```
php app/console doctrine:mapping:import MYBundle php
```

and

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities MYBundle
```

Ok, my entities are now created.
Then I wanted to create basic crud operations, so i run

```
php app/console generate:doctrine:crud
```

Which is supposed to create Controllers,Views and Routing table for the selected models.
The problem is that the routing table isn't generated, so if i navigate to, let's say, /posts, and my index.html.twig contains

```
path('users_show', { 'id': entity.id }) }}
```

My server send a 500 Error.
Symfony doesn't even catch that error and show me the nice formatted exception.

Furthermore if i modify my index.html.twig, it will remain cached until i don't rm -R the /app/cache/dev folder.
Is there a way to disable caching?

[EDIT]

my routing_dev.yml

```
_welcome:
    pattern:  /
    defaults: { _controller: OREBundle:Default:index }

_assetic:
    resource: .
    type:     assetic

_wdt:
    resource: "@WebProfilerBundle/Resources/config/routing/wdt.xml"
    prefix:   /_wdt

_profiler:
    resource: "@WebProfilerBundle/Resources/config/routing/profiler.xml"
    prefix:   /_profiler

_configurator:
    resource: "@SensioDistributionBundle/Resources/config/routing/webconfigurator.xml"
    prefix:   /_configurator

_main:
    resource: routing.yml
```

and my routing.yml

```
_welcome:
    pattern:  /
    defaults: { _controller: OREBundle:Default:index }
_users:
    pattern: /users
    defaults: { _controller: OREBundle:Users:index}
```

Comment: are you hitting `/app_dev.php`? also, post the contents of your `routing.yml` and `routing_dev.yml`

Comment: was hitting /app.php.  now it shows the formatted exception from symfony saying that "Route "users_show" does not exist."  i'll edit my post to add the routing.yml

Comment: what happens when you try `path('users', { 'id': entity.id, 'action': 'show' }) }}`

Comment: the page renders, but i get this url : /app_dev.php/users?id=1&action=edit

Comment: Why do you name the route _users instead of users ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you never ran your command with the `--with-write` option. From the symfony2 docs:

> --with-write: (no) [values: yes|no] Whether or not to generate the new, create, edit, update and delete actions

You can try running your `generate-entities` again with this option.

Comment: I ran the command generate:entities interactively, and it asked me if i wanted the script to generate the actions. I solved by uploading the framework again and building everythin again from scratch